# Why isn's dom updates detected by subsequent dom reads?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm coding a small Vue app. I've got an element which has a data-range property written like this:

```
:data-range="form.appearence.height_min + '/7'"
```

`form.appearence.height_min` will change based on a select element values, selected by the user.

After every select change, I'll read again the data-range and do things based on it.

```
// from the vue app, a watcher
'form.appearence.xps':function(val, oldval){
  // this will properly change the model and the dom as well
  this.$set(this.form.appearence, 'height_min', xps_map[val]);
  this.$emit('xps-updated');
}


// then from another script
this.options.vue.$on('xps-updated', function(){
  this.options.vue.$nextTick(function(){
    console.log($('#test5').data('range')) // issue: this value doesn't change
  }.bind(this))
}.bind(this));
```

My issue is that the range value does change on dom, I can see it from console, but javascript will always read the initial value... For example, at start was 3/7, then it gets changed to 5/7, but `$('#test5').data('range')` will still read 3/7. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll answer by myself. I found out that jquery objects do not follow Vue's dom updates, at least in this case. Therefore, even if dom gets updated by Vue, `$('#test5').data('range')` will always give the initial value.

Instead, by getting the 'real' element with vanilla js, like

```
let range = document.querySelector('#test5').dataset.range;
```

Will always return the updated value.